# Fastest way to add entry to DB if not exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to add set of entries to MySQL DB table. I need to add entry if it doesn't exist, and otherwise send some signal outside that it wasn't added (f.e. return false).

I can check if entry exists (with one query) and add it if not exists with another. However, cause there may be thousands of entries I need to add, I think that extra query is not good.

Can I somehow use just one MySQL query, that would add entry if it doesn't exist and return false if it exists?

Comment: try Insert on Duplicate syntax, it is good for CSV.

Comment: How often will you be doing this? Performing a `SELECT` before every `INSERT` isn't too expensive, so if it's a one-off or a rare operation I don't think you'd save much time.

Comment: Yes, I'm importing them from CSV file, where there can be 1000-10000 of entries. 

Thanks really for your answer, Dai, I forgot that I must first track time, maybe this problem really doesn't need such a fix

Comment: I would be tempted to use INSERT IGNORE (although it semi suppresses errors) and check the affected rows count. If you are importing from a CSV I would also be tempted to just LOAD DATA INFILE the file into a temp table and do the insert from there (or even join the temp table to your existing data table to get the duplicates directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WHERE NOT EXIST syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, address, tele)
VALUES ('John', 'Somewhere', '001')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='value'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To optimize query using WHERE NOT/EXIST queries with insert, you can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, address, tele)
VALUES ('John', 'Somewhere', '001')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE name='value'
);
```

Which can be further optimize using `LIMIT 1` like:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, address, tele)
VALUES ('John', 'Somewhere', '001')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE name='value' LIMIT 1
);
```

Note:`SELECT 1` is faster that `SELECT [column_name]...`